# Flattening RequestParam Object in OpenApi 3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, api-doc

I am migrating from swagger 2 to OpenApi 3.

**Swagger 2 Sample Code**

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "")
        @GetMapping
          public List<Employee> findEmployees(@Valid Dto dto) {
                return employeeService.findEmployees(dto);
                }
```

**OpenApi 3 Code**

```
    @Operation(summary = "")
        @GetMapping
          public List<Employee> findEmployees(@Valid Dto dto) {
                return employeeService.findEmployees(dto);
                }
```

**DTO Class**

```
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Dto {
        private String status;
        private String name;
        private String destination;
    }
```

There is a significant difference in generation of swagger-ui in both cases.

**Swagger 2 shows the DTO object as flattened into individual query params** :

[**Image** Flattening of object as individual query parameters happens in Swagger 2 ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6VJW.png)

**while OpenApi 3 creates a JSON object**:

[**Image** Object doesnot flattens but creates a json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fO9w.png)

I want to have the flattening behavior in OpenApi 3 like the way it used to be in Swagger 2.
Is there any way to achieve the same in OPENAPI 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research i found that a new version of openapiui dependency has been released on 12th of april 2020 and it solves my issue in hand. From version **1.3.2** its available.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The use of Annotation **@ParameterObject** before the query parameter object solves it.

```
   @Operation(summary = "")
        @GetMapping
          public List<Employee> findEmployees(**@ParameterObject** @Valid Dto dto) {
                return employeeService.findEmployees(dto);
                }
```